# Identifying memory management issues

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

```
#include "A.h"
int main (int argc, char*argv[]){
A * p_a1 = new A();
A * p_a2 = p_a1;
delete p_a1;
p_a1 = 0;
delete p_a2 <br>
```

Could this code where A is some class lead to memory management issues? 
My Thoughts: 
The first line will create a pointer to A. I am not sure if this will allocate memory for A, too, or will it just assign an address? The second pointer p_a2 points to the exact location.
 delete p_a1 will delete the allocated memory, which probably didn't have anything p_a1=0, making it null. delete p_a2. We are then deleting the null pointer, which probably won't affect 
 Could this lead to any memory leakage or issues?

Comment: Assigning a null value to `p_a1` has no effect on `p_a2`. (The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers.)

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea for all the new's to have matching delete's, preferably nearby in the code.

Comment: `A * p_a2 = p_a1;` -- After that line, `p_a2` is independent of `p_a1`.  Calling `delete p_a1;` doesn't magically inform `p_a2` that `p_a1` had `delete` called on it.  All of that work of making sure all the pointers that pointed to that object get notified does not exist out-of-the-box in C++ -- you have to maintain this yourself in some way, which makes memory management error-prone in many cases.  If you want to actually share pointers to the same object, there is something in C++ called `std::shared_ptr` that does all of this work.

Comment: Answers are: 1) yes.  2) allocates memory for A from dynamic storage *and* constructs A.  3) incorrect, deleting a dangling pointer is **undefined behavior**.  4) yes, it leads to **undefined behavior** (which qualifies as "issues").

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the same object twice is definitely a memory management issue. `delete p_a1;` does delete the object pointed to by `p_a1`, then `delete p_a2` tries to delete the very same object.

Remember: You are not deleting pointers, but you delete the object they are pointing to.

Raw `new` is always a code smell and a potential source of bugs. Your code should look like this instead:

```
#include "A.h"
int main (int argc, char*argv[]){
   A a;
}
```

---

Frankly, given your question imho one can either only scratch the surface or write a long article to explain important basics. I opted for the first and refer you to a book for more details: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `p_a1` and `p_a2` are independant pointers which *at a time* happen to point to the very same object.

After

```
delete p_a1;
p_a1 = 0;
```

all is fine from a `p_a1` point of view: the object it pointed to has been deleted, and the pointer itself as received a `nullptr` value, so it is now safe to do `delete p_a1` again.

But `p_a2` has not been changed and now points to an object that has reached its end of life. So it has become a *dangling* pointer and dereferencing it or deleting it will invoke UB.

If you want `p_a2` to be **equivalent** to `p_a1` you should make it a reference:

```
A* &p_a2 = p_a1;
```

Now after `p_a1 = 0`, `p_a2` is a reference to a null pointer and it can safely be deleted.

Comment: So what I understand is since the memory pointed to by p_a2 has been deallocated when we did `delete p_a1` so now p_a2 points to a memory address which may not actually belong to the program or may even so that could lead to issues?